# Want to color range A2:P

Tags: excel, vba

I want to color range of A2:P through macro but not able to color. In one of my macro i am using below code but its not working with other. So can anybody tell me simple code to color range A2:P

```
Sub SelectiveColor2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:E" & lastRow).Interior.color = RGB(204, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **Set** *ws*:

```
Sub SelectiveColor2()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim lastRow As Long

   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("A2:E" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Also your code goes to column **E** and not column **P**.

Comment: It worked thanks for help. I was searching over Internet from 2 days. Can we mention sheet name also instead of activesheet?

Comment: @AtulVij  **YES** ......................use something like:.................`Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`